# Names for the levels of a dictionary entry

Tags: dictionaries

What are the names for the different "levels" of a dictionary entry, especially for the Oxford English Dictionary entries displayed by Google?

E.g., I find a LOT of levels in the dictionary entry for the word [like](https://www.google.com/search?q=like+definition). I'll give this a shot:

- "word", (e.g., "like".)
- "homographs", (e.g., "like^1", "like^2", "liked^3". Indicated by "^*". From what I can tell, this is the level at which etymologies are provided)
- "parts of speech", (e.g., "preposition". Indicated by italics.)
- "definitions", (e.g., "1. having the same characteristics or qualities...". Indicated by a tab, and a number if more than one.)
- "specifications" or "sub-definitions", (e.g., "in the manner of". Indicated by two tabs and a bullet)

Does this sound right? Any important edge cases I'm missing here?

Comment: Different homographs (which have different etymologies) are different words.

Comment: The etymology gives the known history of the word, through millennia of levels, occasionally. And "part of speech" is only a small part of the grammatical information that should be there in a good dictionary (e.g, nouns can be mass or count, ruling out *_a bowl of bean_ and *_a bowl of rices_; verbs can take infinitive complements or gerund complements; _rent_ is an active verb, while _own_ is a stative one; etc).